# Get the remote bash shell to use a .bash_history file that is on my local machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tunnel, socat

My environment contains clusters with multiple hosts in each cluster and as such I tend to run similar or equivalent commands on the hosts in such a cluster.

Sometimes, I am ssh-ed into a cluster host and remember that I had run a certain command on another host in this cluster but I can't remember which host I ran it on, however I need to run that command again.
Since every host in the cluster has its own `.bash_history`, I have to log in to each and every one of them and look through the `.bash_history` file to locate that command.

However, if I could use one `.bash_history` file for all hosts in the cluster (e.g. named `.bash_history.clusterX`) then I would be able to search the command in the bash history (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and execute it.
Is that possible?

In my setup shared home directory (via nfs, etc.) is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to leave the relevant commands to execute in an executable file ('`ssh_commands`') in the home folder of each remote user on each machine.
Those `ssh_commands` will include the commands you need to execute on each server whenever you open an SSH session.

To call that file on each SSH session:

```
ssh remoteUser@remoteServer -t "/bin/bash --init-file <(echo 'source ssh_commands')"
```

That way, you don't have to look for the right commands to execute, locally or remotely: your SSH session opens *and* execute right away what you want.